# Quantify a score (or figure-of-merit) of the code style for source code of different sizes

Tags: statistics

I want to have a numeric score  between $0$ and $100$ to reflect the quality of code style for the R source code written by my team members based on some pre-defined rules.

The rules and checks are taken from [lintr](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) and are something standard, such as:

- The length of function and variable names should be less than $32$ characters.
- The commas in the source code should be followed by spaces, but do not have spaces before them.
- There should be no no missing argument is supplied to function calls.
- The source code should have no absolute paths used.
- ...

Assume there are totally $N$ rules.

Let's index each rule by $i \in [1, N]$ and for each rule I create a penalty weight $w_i$ between $0$ and $10$ representing how serious that rule is and how bad it is when that rule is violated. For example, rule for variable name is very critical. I give it a $w_i = 9$. When variable name rule violation is captured from the source code, it represents a more serious issue.

With [lintr](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr) I could obtain, for $i$th rule, how many lines in the source code violates that specific rule $n_i$. Then I normalize the line number by the total number of lines in the source code $n_0$ and get a score $\frac{n_i}{n_0} \in [0, 1]$.

I then caluate the weighted average of this score based on results of all rules and their corresponding penalty weight $w_i$ and obtain a score in $[0, 1]$:

\[ p =\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i \frac{n_i}{n_0}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i} \]

The I define the final score for code style quality with

\[ s = 100 \cdot (1-p) \]

The problem of this score is that, the chance of having a rule violation does not increase linearly with number of lines of the source code. So, for large source code, $n_i/n_0$ could be very small due to large number of $n_0$ (total amount of lines). Therefore the final code style score $s$ could be artificially high for large source code and artificially low for small source code.

And for each different rule, the relation between the chance of violation and the size of the source code is different and unknown. I could only think about the most simply and naïve way of normalization with dividing by the total line number.

Another issue is the variance of the score for source code with different sizes are not homogeneous. For example, for a very short source code with only 2 lines of code, there are only $3$ possible scores $0, 50, 100$. The changes are dramatical from one to another. All possible scores are turn to be like a finite discrete set. However with large files containing thousand of lines, the score could be more like a continuous number in $[0, 100]$. This make it hard and even meaningless when comparing scores from source code file with different sizes.

Is there a way to adjust this score or redefine it completely so that make it fair when use it with source code with different sizes?

**NOTE**: I have posted the same question to the cross validation stack exchange, but get no enough attention. I searched through this math stack exchange and find more questions related to figure-of-merit or quality quantification. So, I think this is a question more relevant to this forum. I will delete my post in cross validation stack exchange when I get an answer here.

Comment: It's unclear to me why having a large $n_0$ would make the score "artificially" low. The score is low because there are fewer mistakes as a proportion of the total amount of work. If it is not relevant how many lines there are, then why do the normalisation at all? I also don't understand the issue with small code bases. Most measures of anything are very variable when dealing with small samples. You would surely not say that the sample mean is a poor measure, simply because it can vary a lot for small samples?

Comment: @preferred_anon Thanks. It is really inspired. I agree the question might be pointless. Assume there are two files of source code from a same programmer. One has only few lines and the other has 5000 lines. There is a same typo in both files. The small file will have a very low score and the large one will have a high score. It is fine for large file, since typo is not systematic error and does not reflect general code quality. But for small file, it is unfair to give low score just due to one typo. I think my question really is how to score small file so that it reflects actual code quality.

Comment: I suspect this is not a question with an objective answer. It really depends how you conceptualise the errors in your code. For example, should a big and a small file be equally penalised for the same error? If so, then you probably want to just count the mistakes and derive a score from that. But code quality normally has an "average" baked into it - if a file with 5 lines has a single typo, then it is surely of a lower quality than a file with 5000 lines in it and only a single typo. So you have to make an arbitrary subjective choice, I think.

Comment: @preferred_anon Thank you for very enlightening discussions. I have 30 predefined checks and rules already programmed. There might be specific rules which require equal penalty regardless of file size. I will review them and may come up with a score combined of both ways, or just use the mean if it is over complicated. Thank you again for the comment. It's really helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help!